# Should you set up firewall rules with a vpn?

Tags: vpn, firewalls

I am using a vpn and trying different firewall rules to keep as secure as possible.  But the VPN company itself tells me not to use a firewall. Does that seem reasonable?

They write:

> "As we've mentioned previously, it is not recommended to have UFW/GUFW
> enabled when connected to our VPN, as it may cause interference and
> lead to possible leaks."

Comment: Why do you want a firewall?

Comment: Their reasoning must be that the majority of users are not network experts and will screw up things, plus their setup may require dynamically allocated ports or whatever. Translation: don't fix what ain't broken. Reasonable ? I think you are entitled to limit your exposure, after all you are connecting to a third-party network. But you are trusting them with your traffic though.

Comment: and why do you want a VPN?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The motivation for a firewall is straightforward in my case. As I am being hacked (and I'm usually not sure how), I am searching for ways to stop this. A firewall and vpn, seemed to me a good place to start.

Comment: You do not need a firewall behind a VPN service. The VPN will stop all inbound connections (they have a firewall).

Comment: "I am being hacked" -- there are very few "hacks" that will be stopped by a firewall on a personal laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is perfectly reasonable. A VPN service does not want to have to deal with the support calls and troubleshooting when people try to configure their own firewalls. So the *recommendation* is not to have one.

They are not saying you *can't* have one. They said they do not recommend it.

And you do not need a firewall if you are using a VPN service. They will block incoming connections, which is the protection you need if you are worried about "getting hacked" from Internet traffic.